Inject List of complex data from Configuration in Spring Boot
I want to inject a data structure from a yaml file that looks like:
default:
  users:
  - id: 1
    login: "user1"
  - id: 2
    login: "user2"

My attempt was to create a user class:
data class User (
  val id: Integer,
  val login: String
)


And then inject it in Spring Boot via:
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "default")
data class UserProperties(val users: List<User>)

or similar to this:
@Configuration
class UserProperties {
  class Properties {
    val users: List<User>? = null
  }

  @get:ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "default")
  @get:Bean
  val properties: Properties
    get() = Properties()
}

In both cases Spring app is failing immediately with
ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server
Is it possible to inject this type of data structure and how to do that?

I've tried your code (first version) and it works fine.  Can you state what version of Spring, whether you use Maven or Gradle and the stack trace of the failed start

@AndrewL you're right. The injection itself works fine, the problem was in test configuration - I misunderstood error source. Thanks for the advice.
